# Batch Comment in Multi-Line Command

Tags: batch-file, sed, comments, multiline

I am wondering if it is possible to have a comment within a batch file command.  Specifically, I have a long `SED` command like the following:

```
@SED -r -e "s/.../.../"^
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    fileName >outFileName
```

I would like to add a comment to each of the "-e" options, as indicated in the following examples:

```
:: Option #1: At the end of the line
@SED -r -e "s/.../.../"^ // First comment
    -e "s/.../.../"^     // Second comment
    -e "s/.../.../"^     // Third comment
    fileName >outFileName

:: Option #2: Between lines
@SED -r
    @REM First comment
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    @REM Second comment
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    @REM Third comment
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    fileName >outFileName
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can the *NIX version of sed handle inline comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try.  I don't have sed so I just tested with echo.

```
@echo off
:: Option #1: At the end of the line
echo SED -r -e "s/.../.../" %= First comment =%^
    -e "s/.../.../" %= second comment =%^
    -e "s/.../.../" %= third comment =%

:: Option #2: Between lines
echo SED -r^
    %= First comment =%^
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    %= second comment =%^
    -e "s/.../.../"^
    %= third comment =%^
    -e "s/.../.../"

pause
```

Output

```
SED -r -e "s/.../.../"     -e "s/.../.../"     -e "s/.../.../"
SED -r        -e "s/.../.../"        -e "s/.../.../"        -e "s/.../.../"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the comment includes the `%` character?  I thought perhaps I could change the comment to `!= My Comment % =!` since I enabled delayed variable expansion, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @JeffG, correct.  Delayed Expansion expands variables when it executes the line of code.  Percent variables are expanded before the code is executed.  The only way to escape a % is to double it.  But in this instance that is not going to work for you.

Comment: Doubling up the parentheses in the comments does appear to work, as long as each of the resulting variables is not defined.  For example, `%= %%does not exist%% =%` is valid since none of `%= %`, `%does not exist%`, or `% =%` are defined.  However, `%= %%windir%% =%` is not valid since `%windir%` is defined.